# what do I type in terminal to compile C code for iphone on mac?

Tags: iphone, c, macos, gcc, compilation

Hey all,
Hoping to compile the "cat" program for iphone4. I figure the command to do so is gcc -somecommandtospecifyiphone. I want to do this on my mac and then just move the file to my iphone later. all compiler errors aside, what command do I type to do this?

Edit: 
Provided its not done via gcc or in a terminal or whatever, how would I accomplish this?

Comment: No, that's how you would compile and install code for the gnuPhone.  Unfortunately the iphone is not a gnuPhone... so you will have a much longer and less direct journey to accomplish this task.

Comment: Cross compiling is not a trivial task. Based on your question, I would say it's way over your head to cross compile for the iphone.

Comment: @Falmarri I asked the question in hopes of an answer on how to do it, not to be told its over my head. When that answer comes along, we will see whether it is or isnt in fact over my head. The fact is you have no clue, nor do I whether it is or isnt. If you have a real answer to my question I would love to hear it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to accomplish isn't trivial for a couple of reasons (assuming you haven't jailbroken your iphone).  first, each app you install is sandboxed, so you can't really pipe things into cat like you would want.  Second, the lower level stuff on iphone is abstracted away, so you can't really bring up a shell and interact with cat.  Finally, software on the iphone must be digitally signed.  Xcode (the apple IDE) takes care of a lot of this stuff for you, but in the end it is still using gcc to (cross)-compile and install iphone software.

Here are some pointers if you still want to try to get this to work:
- jailbreak your phone so you can install non-codesigned software on it
- specify an arm architecture when compiling with gcc, better yet build your project in xcode and allow it to help you.  You can also look into the commandline xcodebuild tool if you really want to stick to the command line.